# React Native: Try to display data from Firebase into a list

Tags: listview, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm trying to display a list with datas from my Firebase DB but I'm stuck right now :/

Here is my code:

Request my datas:

```
  this.tasksRef = firebase.database().ref('/store');
  const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
  });
  this.state = {
   loaded: false,
   dataSource: dataSource
  };
```

Trying to do something if my datas change:

```
 componentWillMount() {
  // start listening for firebase updates
  this.listenForTasks(this.tasksRef);
 }

 listenForTasks(tasksRef) {
  tasksRef.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
   var tasks = [];
   dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
    tasks.push({
      name: child.val().title,
      _key: child.key
    });
   });

   this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tasks)
   });
 });
}
```

And my render:

```
 render(){
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Header text="Account" loaded={this.state.loaded} />
     <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      enableEmptySections={true}
      renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
      style={styles.listView}/>
   </View>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to learn react so thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create your list try the below. First you create a createDataSource function that you can call both on componentWillReceiveProps and on componentWillMount. Then pass this to the list

```
class ListingDemo extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.createDataSource(this.props.listing) // the listing from your firebase connection
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps ({ listing }) {
    // this.props are the old props
    this.createDataSource(listing)
  }

  createDataSource (listing) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    })

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(listing)
  }
}
```

then on your render function

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderRow}
/>
```

Let me know if that helps

UPDATE:
You need to fetch correctly the data from firebase so on the componentWillMount function add the below.

```
tasksRef.on('value', (snap) => {

      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          title: child.val().title,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      createDataSource(items)

    });
```

Comment: So thank you for your help Panagiotis :)                                                                  But I still got an error.

Comment: check my updated answer. You need to fetch correctly the data from firebase

Comment: It's better than earlier but still an error cause my renderRow value is unfortunately empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Here my updated code now:

```
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.props.listing = firebase.database().ref('/store');

     this.state = {
      loaded: false,
     };
    }
    componentWillMount () {
     this.createDataSource(this.props.listing)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps ({ listing }) {
     this.createDataSource(listing)
    }

    createDataSource ({listing}) {
     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
     rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    })

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(listing)
   }

   render(){
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header text="Account" loaded={this.state.loaded} />
      <ListView
       dataSource={this.dataSource}
       renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
     </View>
    );
   }
```

I got this error :

> undefined is not an object (evaluationg 'ref2.listing')

Thanks for your help I try to learn how it's works.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE:

So here's my code now, I got this error

> RenderRow's value is empty

```
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
     rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
   }),
   loaded: false
 };
 this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items');
}

getRef() {
 return firebase.database().ref('/store');
}

listenForItems(itemsRef) {
 itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
  // get children as an array
  var items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    items.push({
      title: child.val().title,
      _key: child.key
    });
  });
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
  });

 });
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
}

render(){
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header text="Account" loaded={this.state.loaded} />
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
    />
  </View>
 );
}
```

:/ :/ :/